# bash: grep only lines with certain criteria

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am trying to grep out the lines in a file where the third field matches certain criteria.
I tried using grep but had no luck in filtering out by a field in the file.
I have a file full of records like this:

```
12794357382;0;219;215
12795287063;0;220;215
12795432063;0;215;220
```

I need to grep only the lines where the third field is equal to 215 (in this case, only the third line)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Put down the hammer.

```
$ awk -F ";" '$3 == 215 { print $0 }' <<< $'12794357382;0;219;215\n12795287063;0;220;215\n12795432063;0;215;220'
12795432063;0;215;220
```

Comment: nice! thank you very much!! didnt know you could do that with awk. awesome!

Comment: The `{ print $0 }` is even superfluous here. Note that this will also keep lines like `abc;def;0215;foo`

Comment: why `awk` would be preferred over `grep`? I never used awk. Somehow it always seems like *awk* ward or _aw_ ful. But never _aw_ esome.

Comment: awk is *designed* for tabular data, whereas grep is more oriented towards free-form text.

Comment: (If the OP wants) you could not match `0215` by using `$3 ~ /^215$/`

Comment: @Shiplu As ignacio says, this is what `awk` was designed for. See how much nicer it is than your grep solution (which, btw, will only work if a row has more or fewer columns)?

Answer (score 2):

grep:

```
grep -E "[^;]*;[^;]*;215;.*" yourFile
```

in this case, awk would be easier:

```
awk -F';' '$3==215' yourFile
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution in pure bash for the pre-processing, still needing a `grep`:

```
while read line; do
  OLF_IFS=$IFS; IFS=";"
  line_array=( $line )
  IFS=$OLD_IFS
  test "${line_array[2]}" = 215 && echo "$line"
done < file | grep _your_pattern_
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple egrep (=`grep -E`)

```
egrep ';215;[0-d][0-d][0-d]$' /path/to/file
```

or

```
egrep ';215;[[:digit:]]{3}$' /path/to/file
```

Comment: What's with the `0-d`? Do you know the final field is always going to be three digits? What do you need the `-E` option for?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
cat your_file | while read line; do
    if [ `echo "$line" | cut -d ";" -f 3` == "215" ]; then
        # This is the line you want
    fi
done
```

Comment: Although correct, better don't cat and pipe and rather use `<` redirection (`while read line; do... done < your_file`). Remember : `cat` is for displaying or for concatenating. Other uses are most of the time useless.

Comment: The `echo` can also be removed by using `cut ... <<< $line`.  However, using `cut` in a loop spawn lots of processes, which can slow down the processing of a large file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sed version to grep for lines where 3rd field is 215:

```
sed -n '/^[^;]*;[^;]*;215;/p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your problem by putting the 3rd field at the beginning of the line:

```
cut -d ";" -f 3 file | paste -d ";" - file
```

then `grep` for the lines matching the 3rd field and remove the 3rd field at the beginning:

```
grep "^215;" | cut -d ";" -f 2-
```

and then you can `grep` for whatever you want.  So the complete solution is:

```
cut -d ";" -f 3 file | paste -d ";" - file | grep "^215;" | cut -d ";" -f 2- | grep _your_pattern_
```

**Advantage**: Easy to understand; **drawback**: many processes.

Comment: +1 Cool recipe that can be useful in other scenarios. Other drawback is that the file is read twice - but in paralell , I guess the disk cache minimizes the impact.